# Need to say if stored procedure variable is null in an open query for use in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure which calls into a linked Oracle server.
Using this code in the `WHERE` clause:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp]
    @SalesOffice Varchar(12),
    @HALTDEBTLETTERS Varchar(12)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Query Varchar(Max)

    -- Set the Query
    SET @Query = 'select 
                    * 
                     from openquery(
                                    [linkedserver],
''
SELECT
c.customer_account, 
c.customer_name, 
c.sales_office,
TRUNC(TO_DATE(''''01/01/1970'''',''''dd/mm/yyyy'''') + FLOOR(c.last_order_date/86400)) AS LastOrderDate,
ed.data_text as HaltDebtLetters
FROM customer c
left join entity_data ed on c.customer_account = ed.ENTITY_KEY1 AND ed.FIELD_NAME = ''''HaltDebtLetters''''
WHERE 
UPPER(sales_office) = ''''' + cast(UPPER(@SalesOffice) as varchar)+ ''''' and (ed.data_text =  ''''' + cast(UPPER(@HALTDEBTLETTERS) as varchar)+ ''''' OR  ''''' (@HALTDEBTLETTERS) + ''''' IS NULL)
ORDER BY sales_office, customer_account
'')
'

    EXEC (@Query)
END
```

I want to test on `sales_office` and `HALTDEBTLETTERS` but I also want users to be able to ignore `HALTDEBTLETTERS` in SSRS but still do the `sales_office` selection.

The above code is erroring out saying

> Incorrect syntax near '@HALTDEBTLETTERS'.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I feel like we need more here; that SQL is not valid on it's own

Comment: The error is because you are missing a `+` before `(@HALTDEBTLETTERS)`. We need more info on what you are actually trying to do

Comment: We need to see *how* you are calling the linked oracle server from TSQL.  There's more than one way to do that.

Comment: It appears that you are using dynamic sql. You cannot debug what you cannot see. You will need to examine the contents of the query you construct. Typically you either print or select the string you build.

Comment: Thanks I have added the full sp

Comment: I dont think that is going to work, as the variable im checking against is in SQL Server but the code it is checking against is ran in Oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two errors.

1. See @Charlieface comment.
2. You may not test your nullable parameter inside your dynamic sql. You need to test it before. I suggest you to change your WHERE condition as below:

   `WHERE UPPER(sales_office) = ''''' + cast(UPPER(@SalesOffice) as
   varchar) + '''' ' +
   case when @HALTDEBTLETTERS is not null then 'and (ed.data_text =      ''''' +
   cast(UPPER(@HALTDEBTLETTERS) as varchar)+ ''''') ' else ' ' end +
   'ORDER BY...`

Aditionali, look if you are not using to many single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the posts above .. it was missing the + before as mentioned by @Charlieface.

Also it wouldnt work becuase it was in the query to the linked server so I changed it to.

```
     IF (@HALTDEBTLETTERS is null)
    BEGIN
    SET @Query = 'select 
                    * 
                     from openquery(
                                    [linkedserver],
''
SELECT
c.customer_account, 
c.customer_name, 
c.sales_office,
TRUNC(TO_DATE(''''01/01/1970'''',''''dd/mm/yyyy'''') + FLOOR(c.last_order_date/86400)) AS LastOrderDate,
ed.data_text as HaltDebtLetters
FROM customer c
left join entity_data ed on c.customer_account = ed.ENTITY_KEY1 AND ed.FIELD_NAME = ''''HaltDebtLetters''''
WHERE 
UPPER(sales_office) = ''''' + cast(UPPER(@SalesOffice) as varchar)+ ''''' and ed.data_text =  ''''' + cast(UPPER(@HALTDEBTLETTERS) as varchar)+ ''''' OR  ''''''
ORDER BY sales_office, customer_account
'')
'
END 
ELSE
BEGIN
SET @Query = 'select 
                    * 
                     from openquery(
                                    [linkedserver],
''
SELECT
c.customer_account, 
c.customer_name, 
c.sales_office,
TRUNC(TO_DATE(''''01/01/1970'''',''''dd/mm/yyyy'''') + FLOOR(c.last_order_date/86400)) AS LastOrderDate,
ed.data_text as HaltDebtLetters
FROM customer c
left join entity_data ed on c.customer_account = ed.ENTITY_KEY1 AND ed.FIELD_NAME = ''''HaltDebtLetters''''
WHERE 
UPPER(sales_office) = ''''' + cast(UPPER(@SalesOffice) as varchar)+ ''''' 
ORDER BY sales_office, customer_account
'')
'
END
```

Comment: You can do it using the IF but you will have two blocks of identical  code unless by one line. Using the CASE you will have only one block of code.